# Does screw decomposition mean that order of rotation and translation does't matter in 3D Euclidean transformation?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

This problem comes from R.Hartley & A.Zisserman [*Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision*](http://cvrs.whu.edu.cn/downloads/ebooks/Multiple%20View%20Geometry%20in%20Computer%20Vision%20(Second%20Edition).pdf) at page 78, the **Result 3.6** says

*Any particular translation and rotation is equivalent to a rotation about a screw axis together with a translation along the screw axis. The screw axis is parallel to the rotation axis.*

To my understanding, order of rotation and translation will make a difference on Euclidean translation. because
$$Rx+t \neq R(x+t)$$
Now decompose translation into $t_{\bot}$ and $t_{||}$, and do screw decomposition as follows:[image]

So whether or not it doesn't matter when exchange the order of translating $t_{||}$ along $\mathbf a$ and rotating about $\mathbf a$?

Comment: If the translation is in the direction of the rotation axis, the order doesn't matter. Otherwise it does.

Comment: All right, it is the case, I just could't ensure this.

Comment: The axis consists of fixed points of the rotation.